# Helm: add a column to helm-buffers-list

Tags: helm, helm-sources

Does anyone know how to add a **column** to **helm-buffers-list** ?

I try to hack it, but just find **helm-buffers-list-cache** contains
buffers names and can't find how to add size or directory (which exists
acquiescently)

```
(defclass helm-source-buffers (helm-source-sync helm-type-buffer)
   ((buffer-list
   :initarg :buffer-list
   :initform #'helm-buffer-list
   :custom function
   :documentation
   "  A function with no arguments to create buffer list.")
    (init :initform 'helm-buffers-list--init)
    (candidates :initform helm-buffers-list-cache) ;;****!!!!!here is candidates
    (multimatch :initform nil)
    (match :initform 'helm-buffers-match-function)
    (persistent-action :initform 'helm-buffers-list-persistent-action)
    (resume :initform (lambda ()
                   (run-with-idle-timer
                    0.1 nil (lambda ()
                              (with-helm-buffer
                                (helm-force-update))))))
    (keymap :initform helm-buffer-map)
    (migemo :initform 'nomultimatch)
    (volatile :initform t)
    (resume :initform (lambda () (setq helm-buffers-in-project-p nil)))
    (help-message :initform 'helm-buffer-help-message)))
```

How can I modify helm-buffers-list?